# Cesium Terrain Builder : Could not open GDAL Dataset

Tags: gdal, terrain, cesium

I am trying to run Cesium terrain Builder on Ubuntu 14.04. 
On running
ctb-tile dem.tif

I get the error:

```
Error: could not open GDAL datasetERROR 4: `dim.tif' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
Error: could not open GDAL datasetError: could not open GDAL dataset
```

I have also tried with the full directory name.

What seems to be the issue ?

Comment: You mention dem.tif, but the error message complains about missing `dim.tif`. Just a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set the full path. This error seems to occur when you only give gdal the name of the file.

In addition, only use ASCII characters in file paths. The (quite common GIS) problem is that non-ASCII characters (like æ ø å) in the path name gets deleted. It looks like GDAL eats the special characters. Use ASCII paths instead.

Furthermore, you can always query `gdalinfo <filename>` to figure out what's going on.

And at last but not least, if you use QGIS, you sometimes may also need to reinstall QGIS is in a folder with only ASCII-characters in the title as well. It's a mess :-)